# Crash on QCAR::CameraDevice::getInstance().init(camera)

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I have `Xcode 6.3.2`, and I have downloaded the latest version of the `iOS SDK 4.2.3`.

I have integrated the SDK and the sample in my current project to add a new feature to my project.

When I launch the application and start the `UserDefinedTargetsViewController`, I have a crash on this line:

```
if (! QCAR::CameraDevice::getInstance().init(camera)) {
```

On the function:

```
// Start QCAR camera with the specified view size
- (bool)startCamera:(QCAR::CameraDevice::CAMERA)camera viewWidth:(float)viewWidth andHeight:(float)viewHeight error:(NSError **)error
{
```

of the class `SampleApplicationSession`.

Screen shot in file attachments

Can someone could help me?

Thank you :)

This is screen shot: 
[image]

Comment: Please post the entire class and error, and remove the Android tag, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and managed to fix it.

Vuforia tries to set an invalid pixel format type. (1647522401)

So I had to swizzle the call **[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:]** using Aspects.

https://github.com/steipete/Aspects

Then I basically check if the format is valid, if it is i let it call otherwise I do nothing.

I've included a gist with the code.

https://gist.github.com/vibrazy/008903e5c493637edb84

Hope that helps